# How to process XML file into C# List<T> on conditional basis?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Here is my sample XML schema that is generated by SQL Server. I want it to assign to `List<class>` in C# using LINQ. I tried it but I am getting six rows but after parsing this XML. I should get only one rows in list.

There some conditions to parse this XML.

- TYPE == 1 then SMS,
- TYPE == 3 then DATA
- TYPE == 2 then MINUTES

XML:

```
<summary>
    <period>Jul-2016</period>
    <providerid>7</providerid>
    <type>1</type>
    <volume>2981655</volume>          
</summary>
<summary>
    <period>Jul-2016</period>
    <providerid>7</providerid>
    <type>2</type>
    <volume>6449570</volume>
</summary>
<summary>
    <period>Jul-2016</period>
    <providerid>7</providerid>
    <type>3</type>
    <volume>7702484</volume>
</summary>
```

Here is my C# class structure. I want to parse this XML schema into a `List<UsageSummary>`. After parsing this there will be only two rows into `List<UsageSummary>`. I have used `XDocument.Parse` for XML parsing. After that, I am using Linq `.Descendants` method but I am getting six rows but output should contain only one rows.

```
public class UsageSummary
{       
        public int carrierID { get; set; }
        public Int64 minutes { get; set; }
        public Int64 sms { get; set; }
        public Int64 data { get; set; }
        public string period { get; set; }
}
```

I have used this code:

```
List<UsageSummary> obj = new List<UsageSummary>();

obj = (from res in xmlDoc.Descendants("summary")
       select new UsageSummary
                  {
                      carrierID = (Convert.ToInt16(res.Element("providerid").Value)),                 
                      period = res.Element("period").Value.ToString(),
                      sms = (Convert.ToInt64(res.Element("SMS").Value)),
                      data = (Convert.ToInt64(res.Element("DATA").Value)),
                      minutes = (Convert.ToInt64(res.Element("MINUTES").Value))
                  }).ToList();
```

Kindly help me with this problem.

Comment: output contain one row, which one, what is condition, and can you share the code you have tried

Comment: I have posted an answer that i used in my code but getting three rows but it should contains single row.

Comment: considering data you have posted, then you should have three rows (without applying any filtering and/or grouping).. are there any others summary xml elements that don't appear in the input data section of your post?

Comment: I think you should specify your requirements, the rules that you have to follow to collect/summarize your data in the list.. for example, collecting for providerid, and eventually if one providerid has more sms data, what have to do? sum, max, etc..

Comment: yes, here the point. I have  repeated data for one month. Like above-given XML data is repeated  for one month. I mean I will have 3 records for each day a month. it means it will be 90 records for the same provider with  a different set of volume, So In that scenario, we can not use Dictionary class here because it can not contain duplicate key(type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group your elements.  You can split the problem into 3 parts so you're not trying to this all at once.

First, map your XML onto a structure that mirrors the XML structure:

```
var items =
    from summary in doc.Descendants("summary")
    select new
    {
       Period = (string) summary.Element("period"),
       CarrierId = (int) summary.Element("providerid"),
       Type = (int) summary.Element("type"),
       Volume = (long) summary.Element("volume")
    };
```

Then group these by `CarrierId` and `Period`. For `Volume`, you want a lookup of all the volumes by `Type`:

```
var volumesByPeriodAndCarrier =
    from item in items
    group item by new {item.CarrierId, item.Period}
    into grouping
    select new
    {
        grouping.Key.CarrierId,
        grouping.Key.Period,
        VolumeByType = grouping.ToLookup(x => x.Type, x => x.Volume)
    };
```

Then you can easily create your summaries.  `CarrierId` and `Period` map directly to your class, and the 3 volumes are where you use your mapping from types to fields and sum the totals:

```
var summaries = volumesByPeriodAndCarrier
    .Select(x => new UsageSummary
    {
        carrierID = x.CarrierId,
        minutes = x.VolumeByType[2].Sum(),
        sms = x.VolumeByType[1].Sum(),
        data = x.VolumeByType[3].Sum(),
        period = x.Period
    }).ToList();
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6qbgC3) for a working demo.

Comment: It is a right solution.But here the point. I have  repeated data for one month. Like above-given XML data is repeated  for one month. I mean I will have 3 records for each day a month. it means it will be 90 records for the same provider with  a different set of volume, So In that scenario, we can not use Dictionary class here because it can not contain duplicate key(type).

Comment: You can use a lookup (i.e. `grouping.ToLookup(x => x.Type, x => x.Volume`) and then do whatever you want in the projection with multiple volumes.  You could sum them, for example: `x.VolumeByType[2].Sum()`.

Comment: Yes, the same I am trying.

Comment: I am not able to do that  like sms=summary.VolumeByType.Contains("1")?Convert.ToInt64(summary.VolumeByType["1"].Sum()):0;

Comment: @Ramdeoangh it's not clear what most of that code is supposed to do - all you need is `Sum()`, it will return `0` in the empty case. I've updated the answer and fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is implemented using a linq "pivoting" technic.

Pivoting consists in collecting different types of data, each of them corresponding to a given data record (or xml nodes in our example), in the fields of one record (or object..).

In our case, each pivot object contains the "set" of different types of data (on which you can operate several aggregation operators) of a specific grouping of the orginal data set.

In particular, it allows to sum `volume` values by `type`, `providerid` and `period`, and it gets zero(`0`) for missing `type` xml element values.

```
List<UsageSummary> obj = new List<UsageSummary>();

obj = (from xmlsummary in doc.Descendants("summary")
       group xmlsummary by new { id = xmlsummary.Element("providerid").Value, period = xmlsummary.Element("period").Value } into summaryGrouped
       select new UsageSummary{
                carrierID = Convert.ToInt16(summaryGrouped.Key.id),
                period = summaryGrouped.Key.period,
                sms = (summaryGrouped.Where(sg => sg.Element("type").Value.Equals("1")).Select(v => Convert.ToInt64(v.Element("volume").Value)).Sum()),
                minutes = (summaryGrouped.Where(sg => sg.Element("type").Value.Equals("2")).Select(v => Convert.ToInt64(v.Element("volume").Value)).Sum()),
                data = (summaryGrouped.Where(sg => sg.Element("type").Value.Equals("3")).Select(v => Convert.ToInt64(v.Element("volume").Value)).Sum())
               }
      ).ToList();
```

Comment: I have repeated data for one month. Like above-given XML data is repeated for one month. I mean I will have 3 records for each day a month. it means it will be 90 records for the same provider with a different set of volume, So In that scenario, we can not use Dictionary class here because it can not contain duplicate key(type).  I am using lookup but after lookup i need to sum because there is duplicate key in lookup , so how to do that?

Comment: In fact I had asked for you just this requirement.. see my comment at your OP!  Why do you confirmed Mager answer as he does the same beahviour  of my query (that it is a compact and correct version of his version)?

Comment: u both has the right answer but here your answer is a little bit compact but good. now what to do next?

Comment: ah ok, I've just read your comments with Mager.. before on the phone I haven't read them.. now I take a look to your problem, but first I ask for you to confirm that your requiremnts are those you have specified in your first comment to my answer

Comment: Hi @Ramdeoangh, I've implemented a new solution. It overcomes your issues and implements your requirements as well as expressed in the first comment. May I have some feedback, please?